# forrt1: severe (170): Program Exception - stack overflow

Tags: windows, fortran, stack-overflow, intel, intel-fortran

and thanks ahead of time for any help!

I have compiled a program (which I did not write) and it works just fine on Mac's but when I try to execute the program on Windows I get the following error message shortly after execution of the program began:

forrt1: severe (170): Program Exception - stack overflow

I am not an ifort or Fortran user, but trying to compile a program for work.

I did an "ifort --version" and I am using Intel Visual Fortran Compiler XE with verion 12.0.0.104.  I have been working on this problem for a few days now and I have tried messing with the flags in the Makefile some, but with no luck.

If I can provide any further information, I'll try to do my best.  Thanks again!

Comment: we can't answer your question without seeing the code. I'd guess the default stack size of the windows compiler is less than on the other platform. Probably have very large stack variables. have very large stack variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following flags during compilation to get more information printed out:

`/traceback /check:all`

`check` will do runtime error checking, `traceback` will tell the compiler to generate extra information when a severe error occurs at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile the program, try the option /heap-arrays to have the compiler place arrays on the heap instead of the stack.   Otherwise try making the stack available to the executable larger.

Comment: Additionally, use /heap-arrays:0 to make sure EVERYTHING goes on the heap.