# Fortran Stack overflow issue

Tags: fortran, stack-overflow

I use boundary element method to deal with some dynamic calculation problem. When I calculate time step 12, the total cell number equals 363, one matrix dimension becomes allocate(363*3,363*3). When the size of a matrix exceeds (1000,1000), how can I deal with this issue?

The error is shown as below

```
forrtl: severe (170): Program Exception - stack overflow
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source
HFMODEL.exe        0019AFB7  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
HFMODEL.exe        00195297  _MAIN__                   306  HFMODEL.f90
HFMODEL.exe        0019CE5F  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
HFMODEL.exe        0019B269  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
HFMODEL.exe        0019B3AD  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
kernel32.dll       76CE336A  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          776198F2  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          776198C5  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have an error in your code. We cannot help you if you don't show it. See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: And please copy the error messages here as text, not just picture. It is important, really. If you don't know how to do it, search "copy text from windows command prompt" or similar. you will get links like https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_dos_copy.mspx or https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/

Comment: Thanks very much. @VladimirF

Comment: Some related pages... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874506/forrt1-severe-170-program-exception-stack-overflow https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/282586

Comment: The code is really needed, there is no other way to help you.